# CSS background-size inheriting

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a very **simple progress bar in HTML5 + CSS3** only. Since I've found, the HTML's `<progress>` tag is very hard to properly style across browsers, I'm using *classic* `<div>` version, but now I'm struggling with its design.

**Here is a simplified version of my current code:**

```css
/* Progressbar wrapper */
.progressbar {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px; /* ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES */
  height: 1em; /* Height should fit to a text line */
  padding: 0.231em; /* Equals to 3px in production setup */
  background-color: dimgray;
  border-radius: 100vmax; /* To make curly sides */
}
/* Progressbar indicator */
.progressbar > div {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: green; /* Fallback for browsers that don't support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%);
  background-size: 100px; /* FIXME: This MUST match wrapper width. Can't inherit!? */
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 100%"></div></div> 100 %<br>
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 85%"></div></div> 85 %<br>
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 75%"></div></div> 75 %<br>
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 50%"></div></div> 50 %<br>
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 25%"></div></div> 25 %<br>
<div class="progressbar"><div style="width: 15%"></div></div> 15 %
```

**Here is how it should look (and how it looks with `background-size: <fixednumber>px`):**

[image]

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/2gt0nv5f/22/

The problem is that progresbar's border-size must currently match the wrapper element size in order to make the color gradient render correctly (red color at the 0% mark, greeen at 100% mark). My goal is to make this progressbar responsive (eg. able to fit any width while maintaining its appearance).

**Here is how it looks when using `background-size: inherit` (this is WRONG):**

[image]

**So my question is:** Is there any way to inherit background-size of the bar from its wrapper? And if not, how would you approach this problem? I'm fine with adding extra elements and/or wrapper, but I'm looking for pure CSS solution. This is because the site I'm building this for doesn't allow embedding any JavaScript or similar stuff.

**What I tried:**

1. I thought it could be solved by using background-size's value "inherit", but this doesn't seem to work, even though it should (at least according to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)). I also tried setting the wrapper's background-size explicitly to "help" inheritance happen, but without any positive effect.
2. I experimented with alternative approach using another `<div>` element, that will cover "unused" part of indicator with wrapper's background-color (growing from the right). Not only it looked weird (no border-radius at the end of progress, which was expected), but on some browsers there were some strange rendering bugs (not all the pixels were covered) so I've ditched it.

To be honest, I'm still a CSS beginner, so I believe I'm missing something obvious here. If anyone can point me the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: .progressbar > div { background-size: inherit; } should work well.

Comment: it may not work due to .progressbar lacks background-size property declaration and background-size it's not a default property. 

https://jsfiddle.net/2gt0nv5f/26/

Comment: check it, i think It's working as you expect https://jsfiddle.net/2gt0nv5f/28/

Comment: why not resize the whole div itself? you might have to wrap it in another div, but then you can just do stuff like `width: 100%;`. In the end the result is the same

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2gt0nv5f/35/

Comment: @JoelBonetR and yjs: I already tried this solution, but as you can see in your fiddle, the color of gradient is evenly distributed across the width of a bar, not the total width of what you would expect to be "100%". Maybe I should have mentioned that in my question, sorry.

Comment: Well, this is because you need an ajax that get the progress value to change the width to see the progress bar runing...

Comment: You can check https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp but you will only find static ones, it may help you

Comment: @giorgio: +1, Now I see what you meant by that. Initially I though that having control over "total" width will be better. But having a mask (as in 
Jacob's answer) proved to be best solution and it is similar to what you implied. Am I right?

Comment: yes exactly, I was proposing pretty much what Jacob did in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I insert another div as mask, so I **don't need** to set wrapper width, just set indicator width, with media query, this could be responsive.

```css
/* Emulate standart website setup */

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Progressbar wrapper */

.progressbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES */
  height: 1em;
  /* Height should fit exactly to a text line */
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  /* Left-offset any text that follows progressbar */
  padding: 0.231em;
  /* Equals to 3px in current setup */
  background-color: brown;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Progressbar */

.progressbar .indicator {
  height: 100%;
  /* Use as much, as the height of wrapper allows */
  border-radius: inherit;
  /* Same as wrapper */
  background-color: green;
  /* Fallback for browsers that don't support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  /* FIXME: This MUST match wrapper width. Can't inherit!? */

}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.small .indicator {
  width: 100px;
}
.middle .indicator {
  width: 200px;
}
.big .indicator {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar big">
  <div class="mask" style="width: 50%">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>Test text

<hr>
<div class="progressbar small">
  <div class="mask" style="width: 70%">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>Test text
<hr>
<div class="progressbar middle">
  <div class="mask" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>Test text
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I apologize for late response, it took me some time to figure out the trick behind `overflow: hidden;`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good time to consider CSS variable:

```css
.progressbar {
  margin:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: var(--size,100px);
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.231em;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: calc((1em - 0.231em) * 2);
}


/* Progressbar */

.progressbar>div {
  height: 100%;
  /* Use as much, as the height of wrapper allows */
  border-radius: inherit;
  /* Same as wrapper */
  background-color: green;
  /* Fallback for browsers that don't support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%);
  background-size: var(--size,100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
  <div style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>

<div class="progressbar">
  <div style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>

<div class="progressbar" style="--size:200px">
  <div style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>

<div class="progressbar" style="--size:200px">
  <div style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.progressbar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:10px;
  width: var(--s,100px);
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.231em;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%) content-box,
    grey;
  border-radius: calc((1em - 0.231em) * 2);
  box-shadow:calc(-1*var(--p)*var(--s,100px)) 0 0 inset grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar" style="--p:0.5">
</div>

<div class="progressbar" style="--p:0.2">
</div>

<div class="progressbar" style="--s:200px;--p:0.7">
</div>

<div class="progressbar" style="--s:250px;--p:0.3">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 That's very nice solution, but according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables CSS variables aren't supported in Internet Explorer at all.

Comment: @Electrix are you suprised ? :) all the good stuffs aren't support in IE ;)

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* Emulate standart website setup */
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333333;
}

/* Progressbar wrapper */
.progressbar {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px; /* ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES */
  height: 1em; /* Height should fit exactly to a text line */
  margin-right: 0.4em; /* Left-offset any text that follows progressbar */
  padding: 0.231em; /* Equals to 3px in current setup */
  background-color: g;
  border-radius: calc((1em - 0.231em) * 2); /* Height/2 to make curly sides */
/* ADDED background-size delcaration to the parent element */
  background-size: 50px auto;
}
/* Progressbar */
.progressbar > div.aa {
  height: 100%; /* Use as much, as the height of wrapper allows */
  border-radius: inherit; /* Same as wrapper */
  background-color: green; /* Fallback for browsers that don't support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    red 0%,
    yellow 50%,
    green 100%
  );
  /* NOW it can inherit parent background-size property */
  background-size: inherit; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Progressbar test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="progressbar"><div class="aa" style="width: 50%"></div></div>Test text
 </body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
You can inherit default properties without declaring them on the paren itself, but when there's no default value you need to declare it on the parent before trying to inheriting on the child.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem - the progressbar color gradient should only contain red and yellow at 50% in your example. Thanks anyway!